# How to add +1 to a value between function

Tags: python, user-accounts

I want to add an id to each user that have just registered an account. The way the id works will be like the first user register will have 1(number) as his or her id, the second user will have 2, the third will have 3 and so on. There is no issue to have 1 for the first user id, but as the second, third and more user register, their id still remained as 1. Is there a way that I can keep on adding 1 to the next user id?

```
customer_list = []

def customer_page():
     print('customer page accessed')
     opt = input("press '0' to signup another account: ")
     if opt == '0':
          signup()

def signup_success(f,i,n,p):
     f = 1
     if f == 1:
          i += 1
          customer_list.append([i,n,p])
          print(customer_list)
          customer_page()

def signup():
     username = input('please enter your username: ')
     password = input('please enter your password: ')
     flag = 0
     id = 0
     signup_success(flag,id,username,password)
signup()
```

Comment: You can e. g. read the last id in the "customer_list" and add 1. Without a previous customer start with 1 as id.

Comment: ok, by using return ?

Comment: To get id for new customer you could just use id = `1 + len(customer_list)` (before the new customer is added).  As an aside: in function signup you used descriptive variable names in the call to signup_success.  Why did you only use one letter variable names in funciton signup_success itself (which had me wondering what the purpose of each variable)?

Comment: Thank you DarrylG, I never thought of this way...

Comment: I tried to use flag to trigger the +1 for for i(the id = 0)

Comment: @JacksonTai--Do you  see why "I tried to use flag to trigger the +1 for for i(the id = 0) " doesn't work with localized variables?

Comment: @DarrylG Is it because when the signup function that I run in the customer_page function will run the same signup function again which contain id = 0 again ?

Comment: @JacksonTai-lcal variables in a function invocation are held in a stack frame.  The stack frame is destroyed when the function exits.  Thus, it doesn't matter what previous settings where performed to local variables since they disappear upon function exit.  Variable `customer_list` is a global variable so it is maintained through different function invocations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice how the length of your `customer_list` is always equal to the id of the last customer you added. You can simply make the id of the next customer equal to the length of `customer_list` plus one.

```
customer_list = []

def customer_page():
     print('customer page accessed')
     opt = input("press '0' to signup another account: ")
     if opt == '0':
          signup()

def signup_success(f,n,p):
     f = 1
     if f == 1:
          i = len(customer_list) + 1
          customer_list.append([i,n,p])
          print(customer_list)
          customer_page()

def signup():
     username = input('please enter your username: ')
     password = input('please enter your password: ')
     flag = 0
     signup_success(flag,username,password)
signup()
```

I tried to leave everything else untouched, though I'm honestly not sure what your `flag` variable is for.

Comment: I was trying to use the flag to trigger the + 1 for id